# Switching Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, pcb-design, switching-regulator

I am fairly new to tinkering with electronics and wanted to ask for some help.

I am undertaking a small project where I have approximately 20V input into a PCB and want a 5V rail as well as a 3.3V rail with a maximum of 100mA per rail. I want the ability to turn off the 5V rail when the battery supply gets low. I want to use a pure switching regulator with an enable pin where, using a microcontroller, I can use the enable to signal the regulator to shut off the 5V rail. I also want high efficiency. Any tips on how to get started?

I have been researching a lot, but don't really know where to start. Any tips or guideline would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a decent plan that could work. Digikey has a wide variety of DC-DC converters, and you can narrow the selection by selecting parameters. In your case, you would want Vin(min) to be 15 or 18V, I guess. Vout is 5V and 3.3V. Iout is 100mA. That should narrow it down a bit. If the 20V is from a battery, you will want to give some thought to power management. Some DC-DC converters draw a lot of power (several mA) when idle. Look for converters with low quiescent current.

Comment: This question may get closed as "too broad" but I think people will try to help you in the comment section. When you have a more specific question about a specific part, post another question.

Comment: If you do really want to layout your own power supply system (a daunting task for a novice!) then you'll find it instructive to play around with LTSpice (a free simulation tool from Linear Technology).  All LT power products have spice models AND pre-built schematics that you can simulate and tweak to your own needs.  Their datasheets often have a recommended PCB layout guide for best performance. (Disclaimer: I don't work for LT but I do routinely use their products.  Analog Devices also make excellently supported products with splendid datasheets).

Answer (score 2):

Designing switching regulator is not trivial task, especially if efficiency is important.
If you want to achieve your goal fast and cheap, I would suggest to you to buy already available modules, that are able to step down voltages to 5 and 3,3V. You can order such modules with maximum current of 300mA for around 50cents.
You can focus on circut for battery voltage detection. Simple voltage divider on base of NPN transistor, which will cut off power to step down module would be simplest solution. For more complex/efficient ways to cut off power to module, consult Mr. Google, he has plenty of knowledge on this topic. For example [this](http://electronicdesign.com/power/almost-ideal-low-battery-cutoff-circuit-draws-only-12-mua) is one of fancy solutions.

Comment: @Woss: No, not really, at least not when using a off the shelf chip.  Datasheets and app notes from major reputable manufacturers give you lots of guidance.  Beginners can do this, although they need to be careful, read the datasheet, and pay attention to the details.  Scaring them off this is doing them a disservice.

Answer (score 0):

Designing a switching regulator is not that hard if you follow all the directions in the datasheet carefully.

You want to drop 20 V to 5 V at 100 mA.  There are quite a number of chips out there that cover that.  Take a look at Microchip, and TI for starters.

This chips come with the switch built in.  You add input caps, the inductor, output caps, and sometimes a resistor divider for the feedback to set the voltage.  None of this is hard as long as you pay attention to the details.

The tricky part is not designing the circuit (that's basically right off the datasheet), but designing the right layout.  Often that's suggested in the datasheet too.  Keep the loop current in mind when the switch switches off.  The current thru the inductor stays the same instantaneously, but it suddenly comes thru the diode instead of thru the switch.  Keep the inductor - diode - capacitor current loop short.